# AES-GCM -- what is ICV and what happens if I don't use it

Tags: aes, terminology, gcm

I am interested in using AES-GCM and after hours of reading on Internet I still have a few questions:

What will ensure the ICV, is it only Integrity ? If I don't need it on my purpose, can I spare it and still have secure encrypted data on my channel ? (If integrity is not verified, my packet will be dropped anyway)

our aim is just to encrypt data so that no one can get the information.

Thanks

Comment: in my opinion, ICV just exist in TKIP encryption mode, isn't it?
You can refer it from here [TKIP](https://mrncciew.com/2014/09/13/cwsp-tkip-encryption-method/)

Answer (score 4):

ICV is the integrity check value (beware that it may also mean Initial Chaining Value). You cannot do without for GCM mode.

I'm not sure what you mean with: "If integrity is not verified, my packet will be dropped anyway". GCM uses an authentication tag which provides *cryptographic* integrity. Unless you have another way of adding *cryptographic* integrity then you cannot just skip verifying the tag.

If you do have another authentication tag, say HMAC over the ciphertext, then you don't need GCM. You could use AES-CTR mode instead. Except for some changes during initialization AES-CTR mode is used within GCM to provide confidentiality.

Beware that GCM and CTR modes **do** directly leak the plaintext size and possiblty timing information. That's something to solve - or not - at protocol level.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.   What I meant by ICV was "Integrity Check Value", which from what you said seems to be the AUTHENTIFICATION TAG.

Comment: Ah, don't you love these acronyms :)

Comment: I'd also point out that in *many* cryptosystems, not verifying the authenticity of the tag can counterintuitively result in partial or full plaintext recovery.

Comment: @StephenTouset Are you referring to things like plaintext / padding oracle attacks in transport protocols?

Comment: Yeah. Those specific attacks don't apply to CTR-based ciphers, but at this point I'm instinctually wary of any scheme that provides confidentiality but not authenticity.